# pattern of regex

Tags: java, regex

I am new in Regex, I want to validate words with at least 6 characters and max 30 and should start with letters only but it can contain numbers and underscore starting from second position.I used this pattern but it failed in tests.

```
String pattern = "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*{6,30}$";
```

Comment: Try removing the `*` after your second character class. You have two quantifiers there and it's not a valid regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
String pattern = "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{5,29}$";
```

- You must not use `*` before range quantifier `{5,29}`.
- Using `{5,29}` because 1 character is already at the start.

You can also use this shortened regex:

```
String pattern = "^[A-Za-z]\\w{5,29}$";
```

As `\w` (word character) is equivalent of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Also, if using `matches()`, the anchors `^` and `$` are redundant/unnecessary.